# How do I reference a cell from a sheet depending on the tab name

Tags: excel, reference, excel-indirect

I have summary tab and tabs for each month of the year. On the summary sheet, I have cells that correspond to the running balance of accounts for the on going month. Each month a new tab is created and I want the cells in the summary tab to automatically take the new month's amount.
My running balance for accounts are all situated in row 39 with an offset of 5 and will be the same for each new month tab.

Example:

```
Balance of Product A: E39
Balance of Product B: E44
Balance of Product C: E49
```

On my summary tab, I have three cells all referring to those three products.
I inserted the `today()` formula in cell `A1` so that I could take the `MONTH(A1)` and with an indirect on the cells I would like to link but I can't figure it out.

Comment: are your month on the sheet name numerical or string?  ie  Month 1, 1, or January?'

Comment: Look at the `=TEXT(A1,"MMMM")` for getting the name of the month to dump into your INDIRECT.  All depends on how you named your individual work sheets as to what needs to be pulled and now to concatenate you cell references.

Comment: Your problem is caused by the design of your model. I wouldn't use a separate sheet for each month. Instead, place your data on ONE sheet with a month column (there probably already is a date column, which means you do not need an additional month column). This means summarizing your data is easily done using a pivottable.

Comment: thank you forward Ed. figured it out with INDIRECT("'"&TEXT(L2,"mmm")&"'!"&F26)                  L2 being the today() and F26 being the cell reference

Comment: jkpieterse, cant do so although your idea would be great. it was given as an assignment to me due to the users who will enter data. its to make it more clear for them. thank you though